# Have image and text on top of another image

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

So here is my goal, I want to have image(aka that's my logo) on top of another which is basically the background. So the background image has the logo on it and also some text and both are centered. Now here is my problem, because I set position to relative and absolute, when I resize the window, my images are not responsive, meaning the logo and the text aren't centered anymore.

So what I had to do, was put the texts and the logo in a div and make the background of that div the other image (using background-url in css) the other image background but that's not efficient. So I have this so far:

```css
#pictures {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background: url('http://cdn-s-www.lalsace.fr/images/3CC1D55D-083C-44F1-B484-2D315D21D529/JDE_V0_07/(disney).jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}

#logo {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: none !important;
}

#line1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  font-family: 'IM Fell Double Pica', serif;
}

#line2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  font-family: 'IM Fell Double Pica', serif;
}
```

```html
<div class=" ui centered grid">
  <div id="pictures" class="ui containcer">
    <h1 id="line1">Service - Awareness - Commnuity Outreach</h1>
    <img id="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/bBHabb/slide.png">
    <h1 id="line2">Sophomores Leaders Impacting, Developing, and Educating</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

So here is my question : How can I fix the responsiveness problem without having to use the background-url property (So just have img tags in myhtml)? And fyi I am using Semantic UI instead of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to mention that this would be a great use of css grid. But to answer your question and to pick up from what you have started.  In order to make your images responsive without using background you need them to have a width: 100% and a height: auto. I modified your code a bit to show this would work in your question.  Notice I made a **wraper** class with the position of relative and an **inner** class with position of absolute.  The **inner** class contains your text and can text-align: center here. Your text and logo will now be on top of the image and centered.  You will need media queries to change your text size to fit within the image on smaller screens. If you want to vertically align your inner class you might want to check out this link: http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ for some more details.

```
    .res-image {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
    }
    #logo {
       width: 30%;
       height: auto;
       padding-top: 20px;
    }

   #line1 {
       font-size: 30px;
       color: white;
       padding-top: 40px;
       margin-bottom: 4%;
       letter-spacing: 0.1em;
       -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
       text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 
       1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
       font-family: 'IM Fell Double Pica', serif;
   }

   #line2 {
       font-size: 30px;
       color: white;
       letter-spacing: 0.1em;
       -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
  }

<div class="wrapper ui centered grid">
    <img class="res-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/gjfJAR/DSC_0041.jpg">
    <div class="inner ui containcer">
        <h1 id="line1">Service - Awareness - Commnuity Outreach</h1>
        <img id="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/bBHabb/slide.png">
        <h1 id="line2">Sophomores Leaders Impacting, Developing, and 
        Educating</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```